# Setting up multi node clusters for running mapreduce programs

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, cluster-computing, bigdata

I need the step by step guide to setup a multinode cluster on Centos (linux) machines to run  hadoop map reduce program. I have tried running MR programs in single machine (Standalone mode ) and i am able to run. Now I have 3 - 4 linux machines which i want to configure as a cluster.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop installation is same as in the single mode. Difference between only in the config files.

You can follow this tutorial which is very nice and helpful.
http://javadev.org/docs/hadoop/centos/6/installation/multi-node-installation-on-centos-6-non-sucure-mode/

Comment: Actually i want to setup a  cluster (example : 1 namenode and 2 datanodes). hadoop installation in cluster is the next part.

Comment: I had followed this tutorial before, you can have a look.
 http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/